# Determine hardware specs and OS version of SSAS box using XMLA or a DMV?

Tags: ssas, xmla, dmv

At my current project, SSAS is running on a standalone server and I'd like to know the hardware specs (CPU, Memory, etc) and OS version.

The catch is I don't have access to the OS (or even remote access to perfmon or eventvwr) and the DBA's have so far ignored my requests.  In the meantime, I'm wondering if there's a XMLA command I can run or a SQL query against one of the DMVs that will provide this information.

Also, I have admin rights to the SSAS instance and can run Profiler traces against it, so if there's another way, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find out hardware or operating system specifications through SSAS.

Comment: guess I'll just have to wait for the DBAs to respond. cheers!